# Изменить текст в одной ячейке при клике на другую

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно, чтобы при клике на кнопку, текст в определённом `<td>` менялся на некоторый заданный.

```js
function change(r) {
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById('myTable')
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Один</td>
    <td>Два</td>
    <td><input type="button" class="change" value="Три" onclick='change(this)' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример смены текста:

```js
function change(r) {
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  // Для первой ячейки в том же ряду, где находится кнопка
  r.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('TD')[0].innerText = 'Три';
  // Для второй ячейки в ряду с индексом #0
  table.getElementsByTagName('TR')[0].getElementsByTagName('TD')[1].innerText = 'Четыре';
}
```

```html
  <table id="myTable">
  <tr>
  <td>Один</td>
  <td>Два</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="change" value="Три" onclick='change(this)'/></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: А если будет не одна строчка, а много? Получается что он в итоге меняет для 1й строки всегда, хотя кликается кнопка на следующих любых.

Comment: для текущей строки: 
r.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('TD')[0].innerText = 'Три';
для конкретной строки:
  table.getElementsByTagName('TR')[0].getElementsByTagName('TD')[1].innerText = 'Четыре';

Comment: Вы лучше отредактируйте сообщение, а не в комментарии текст вставляйте.